# Неоднозначный вызов конструктора

Tags: c++, конструктор

Уважаемые друзья, у меня наблюдается следующая проблема. Есть такой код:

```
 class Verylong
 {
 public:
    Verylong (long x = 0) { enter(x);}
    Verylong (const Verylong& vrl) : _sign(vrl._sign), lnum(vrl.lnum) {/*empty*/}
    explicit Verylong (const std::string& str) { enter(str);}    
    explicit Verylong (const char* ch) { std::string str(ch); enter(str);}
    // ...
};
```

При вызове

```
return Verylong(0);
```

я получаю следующую ошибку:

> D:\c++\verylong.h: In member function 'my::Verylong
>   my::Verylong::operator*(const my::Verylong&) const':
>   D:\c++\verylong.h:461:30: error: call of overloaded 'Verylong(int)' is
>   ambiguous
>                return Verylong(0);
>                                 ^ D:\c++\verylong.h:461:30: note: candidates are:
>
> D:\c++\verylong.h:58:22: note: my::Verylong::Verylong(const char*)
>                explicit Verylong (const char* ch) { std::string str(ch); enter(str);}
>
> ^ D:\c++\verylong.h:56:22: note: my::Verylong::Verylong(const string&)
>                explicit Verylong (const std::string& str) { enter(str);}
>                         ^
>
> D:\c++\verylong.h:54:13: note: my::Verylong::Verylong(const
>   my::Verylong&)
>                Verylong (const Verylong& vrl) : _sign(vrl._sign), lnum(vrl.lnum) {/*empty*/}
>                ^
>
> D:\c++\verylong.h:52:13: note: my::Verylong::Verylong(long int)
>                Verylong (long x = 0) { enter(x);}

В чём дело? Откуда берётся неоднозначность и как её правильно устранить?

Answer (score 6):

Исправить ошибку выше довольно просто:

```
return Verylong(0L);  // Здесь больше нет ошибки
```

Проблема в том, что используя `Verylong(0)` Вы получаете неоднозначность, т.к. `0` имеет тип `int`, а у Вас нет конструктора, принимающего тип `int`. Зато есть 3 конструктора, которые могли бы поучаствовать в перегрузке:

- `Verylong(long x = 0)` - требует одной конвертации из `int` в `long`
- `Verylong(const char* ch)` - требует одной конвертации из `0` в `const char*`
- `Verylong(const std::string& str)` - требует 2 конвертации, сначала в `const char*`, потом создаётся временный объект `std::string`. В терминах стандарта сначала происходит *standard conversion*(`0`-> `const char*`), затем *user-defined conversion*(`std::string(const char*)` конструктор), затем `standard conversion`(`identity`). Подробнее в стандарте `C++(13.3.3.1.2)`:

> A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a userdefined conversion (12.3) followed by a second standard conversion sequence. If the user-defined conversion
>   is specified by a constructor (12.3.1), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the
>   type required by the argument of the constructor. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a conversion
>   function (12.3.2), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the implicit object
>   parameter of the conversion function.

Так вот, с точки зрения компилятора первый и второй случаи абсолютно равнозначны и, следоваетльно,- ошибка.
Если же Вы явно указываете, что константа типа `long`, то конструктор `Verylong(long x = 0)` более не требует конвертации и однозначно выигрывает "гонку" перегрузок.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь в том, что второй конструктор, требующий двух конвертаций, участвует в конкурсе.

Comment: @Shamov, так Вы проверьте. Закомментируйте другие конструкторы и убедитесь сами.

Comment: Проверил. Этот конструктор используется только тогда, когда передаётся 0, который уже можно интерпретировать как const char*.

Comment: Двух конвертаций не происходит. Да, в случае с нулём конструктор действительно участвует, но не потому, что из int можно двумя конвертациями получить string. Во-первых, нельзя. Во-вторых, две конвертации стандарт запрещает.

Comment: @Shamov: А почему от тогда участвует? Хм.

Comment: @Shamov, доказательства своим словам приложите? Доказательства моим можете поискать в стандарте C++ 13.3.3.1.2

Comment: @ixSci: Вот послала так послала (ц) Вы бы привели цитату из стандарта (нужную часть), а не только номер раздела.

Comment: Уточняю. Из int в const char* неявного преобразования не существует. Но любая нулевая *константа* может рассматриваться компилятором как указатель - вот откуда неоднозначность.

Comment: @ixSci Даже после обновления ответ все ещё создаёт впечатление, что существует неявное преобразование из любого int, а не только из нуля.

Comment: @ixSci Хорошо. Теперь осталась всего одна проблема. Она состоит в том, что превращение нуля в указатель вообще не считается преобразованием. Даже в смысле standard conversion. Нулевая константа - это уже готовый указатель.

Comment: @Shamov, Стандарт C++ 4.10/1 - "A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to
zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a null pointer conversion"

Comment: @ixSci "Null pointer constant" - это слово NULL, а не число 0.

Comment: @Shamov, со стандартом решили поспорить? Я же Вам уже всё привел, даже стандарт открывать не надо. Всё, что нужно есть в ответе и комментариях, если бы Вы хотели разобраться, то разобрались. Но мне кажется, что Вам нужен спор, ради спора. Мне он не нужен.

Comment: @ixSci Не со стандартом, а с вашей неправильной его трактовкой.

Comment: @Shamov, "A null pointer constant is **an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type that evaluates to _zero_** or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t". Что такое 0? 0 это expression, какого типа? const int, значит 0 это **integral constant expression**. 0 evaluates to zero? А есть сомнения? В общем я всё скзаал и добавить мне нечего.

Comment: @ixSci Из того, что NULL "evaluates to zero" никак не следует, что число 0 тоже "evaluates to zero". Оно уже "zero".

Comment: @Shamov, да причём тут NULL. Откройте 5.19 и читайте до просветления, NULL это просто макрос он НЕ ИМЕЕТ НИКАКОГО **ОСОБОГО** УПОМИНАНИЯ В СТАНДАРТЕ.

Comment: @ixSci В том-то и дело, что он тут ни при чём. Но это вы зачем-то приводите нерелевантные выдержки из стандарта. Да, это просто макрос. Но он упоминается в стандарте как "null pointer constant".

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22894/discussion-between-ixsci-and-shamov).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23012/discussion-on-answer-by-ixsci---).

Answer (score 1):

```
Verylong (int x = 0) { enter(x);}
```

Comment: нужен именно long, да и int ничего не изменит так как 0 приводится (судя по ошибке) к const char*

Comment: @vlad4378, разве?

Comment: @vlad4378, http://ideone.com/emKvcX

Answer (score 0):

Один из конструкторов лишний, и очевидно что это `(const char* ch)` т.к. он делает то же самое что и `(const std::string& str)`.

Comment: идея как раз в том, чтобы передавать конструктору как литералы так и string

Comment: @vlad4378 Можно передавать оба типа в первый конструктор. Просто мысль немного неясно была сформулирована. Лишним является не один из конструкторов, а строго второй.

Comment: точно, я и не подумал. спасибо

Comment: В данном случае он лишний, но в общем случае он будет делать ненужное создание строки.

Comment: @Abyx, а чем просто конструктор с интом не угодил?

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы передаете в конструктор 0? Можно же не передавать ничего, будет 0 по умолчанию.

```
return Verylong();
```

А про причины такого поведения компилятора вам уже сказали.

Comment: возможно класс буду использовать не только я, откуда человеку знать что ноль передавать нельзя?

Comment: Компилятор человеку подскажет.